# Postgresql connection pooling in Erlang

Tags: postgresql, erlang, connection-pooling

I am looking for a robust connection pooling library for Postgresql.

Something similar to https://github.com/dweldon/riakpool would be great.

Comment: Quick Google search reveals https://github.com/josephwecker/epgsql_pool - maybe it's worth trying out

Comment: May worth, but it is broken and doen't work at the moment.

Comment: I've had a much better experience with egobrain's fork: https://github.com/egobrain/epgsql_pool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poolboy is a pretty good general-purpose pooling library: https://github.com/devinus/poolboy

It comes with an example of how to use it with pgsql (scroll down the README file).